# Error while creating temporary path for asset image

Tags: flutter

I use this code to create a temporary path for the default profile picture asset in flutter:

```
  Future<File> getPfpFromAssets(String path) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load(path);

    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }
```

And then I call the function like this:

```
            // Upload pfp
            File defaultPfp = await getPfpFromAssets('images2/defaultpfp.png');
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

            storage.ref("$_username/profile_picture.png").putFile(defaultPfp);
```

I keep getting this error telling me that the temporary path doesn't exist when I try to use it:

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/923DC97E-7B7B-4CFB-9ACB-DC0080C71ABB/Library/Caches/images2/defaultpfp.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

What in my code is incorrect? Is there an easier way to create a file from this image asset to upload it?

Comment: How do I do that? I’m assuming it would show nothing since the error says the path doesn’t exist

Answer (score 0):

The temporary file path doesn't exist because its parent folder `images2` doesn't exist! Just create it before writing:

```
final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
await file.parent.create(recursive: true);
```

Note that we use `recursive: true` to create the whole ancestor folders, for example, if we use `images2/a/b/c/defaultpfp.png`